# Access to a json array of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/8Q4Lf/3/

I am retrieving an array on **json** and storing it in a hidden `input` with this function:

```
$.post("http://"+ document.domain + baseUrl + "/tickets/getCategoryDepartmentRelation/",
    function(dat){
        $('#departmentsByCategory_array').val(JSON.stringify(dat));         
});
```

The call return this value:

```
{
    "Investigation Request": [
        "Client server",
        "Interface",
        "Engine"
    ],
    "Configure Planning": [
        "Interface",
        "Engine"
    ],
    "Bug Report": [
        "Client server",
        "Interface",
        "Engine",
        "Database"
    ],
    "Development Request": [
        "Interface",
        "Dev Management",
        "Database",
        "Client server",
        "Engine"
    ],
    "Suggestion Box": [
        "Dev Management"
    ],
    "Post Site Feedback": [
        "Web"
    ]
}
```

Which is the `json` representation of this array:

```
Array
(
    [Investigation Request] => Array
        (
            [0] => Client server
            [1] => Interface
            [2] => Engine
        )

    [Configure Planning] => Array
        (
            [0] => Interface
            [1] => Engine
        )

    [Bug Report] => Array
        (
            [0] => Client server
            [1] => Interface
            [2] => Engine
            [3] => Database
        )

    [Development Request] => Array
        (
            [0] => Interface
            [1] => Dev Management
            [2] => Database
            [3] => Client server
            [4] => Engine
        )

    [Suggestion Box] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dev Management
        )

    [Post Site Feedback] => Array
        (
            [0] => Web
        )

)
```

This fills the `input` with this data:

```
<input type="hidden" name="demo" value="{&quot;Investigation Request&quot;:[&quot;Client server&quot;,&quot;Interface&quot;,&quot;Engine&quot;],&quot;Configure Planning&quot;:[&quot;Interface&quot;,&quot;Engine&quot;],&quot; Bug Report&quot;:[&quot;Client server&quot;,&quot;Interface&quot;,&quot;Engine&quot;,&quot;Database&quot;],&quot; Development Request&quot;:[&quot;Interface&quot;,&quot;Dev Management&quot;,&quot;Database&quot;,&quot;Client server&quot;,&quot;Engine&quot;],&quot;Suggestion Box&quot;:[&quot;Dev Management&quot;],&quot;Ticket Site Feedback&quot;:[&quot;Web&quot;]}" id="departmentsByCategory_array">
```

I can get the full array with this:

```
$('#departmentsByCategory_array').val();
```

But I am trying to retrieve the values for only one element, for example *"Configure Planning"*.

How can I do it to play with those values inside Javascript or jQuery? (loop, compare...)

Comment: Why to store json string in input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = JSON.parse($('#departmentsByCategory_array').val());
data['Configure Planning']; //returns Configure Planning array
```

Comment: But what I want is just the subarray. For example "Configure Planning". How can I get it?

Comment: It is not working for me. I get an "undefined" value when i print it with an `alert` or with `console.log` function. Although the `data` value is an array which i can see printing it in console.

Comment: @Steve your fiddle contains the representation of the json , not the actual JSON string. you're alerting a string.

Comment: The hardcoded value in your hidden input field is not JSON. I assumed it was the JSON object you have mentioned under "The call return this value:
"

Comment: @janith I made a mistake creating the fiddle, sorry. But it was correctly posted on here.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. You are returning an extra space in your json representation so it's `" Bug Report"` you want to access and *not* `"Bug Report"`.

```
alert(data[' Bug Report']);
```

Modified fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8Q4Lf/2/

The same goes for the key `" Development Request"`.

```
alert(data[' Development Request']);
```